# Is it possible to create elements from html returned by .html()?

Tags: jquery

Has expected, the following jQuery will create nodes from the html :

```
var nodes = $( "<li>ABC</li><li>DEF</li>" );
```

Now, consider the following html :

```
        <ul class="foo">
            <li>ABC</li>
            <li>DEF</li>
        </ul>
```

My question, why does the following returns an error message instead of the nodes ?

```
var html = $( "ul.foo" ).html();
var nodes = $( html );
```

The error message is :

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <li>ABC</li>
            <li>DEF</li>
```

You can see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/HDk47/

Comment: because there is a space,new line before the html tags, jquery now requires that html start at the very beginning of the string for it to be recognized as html

Comment: To support Patrick's claim: *"As of 1.9, a string is only considered to be HTML if it starts with a less-than ("<") character."* http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring. In your HTML, there is a line break and  spaces between the opening `<ul>` tag and the first `<li>` tag and those will be included in the output of `.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's parsing heuristics do not like the leading whitespace in `html`.

Removing the whitespace fixes the problem:

```
var html = $.trim( $( "ul.foo" ).html() );
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDk47/1/)**.

Update: Felix Kling [dug up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066367/is-it-possible-to-create-elements-from-html-returned-by-html#comment24679449_17066367) the [documentation reference](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring) way before I was able to.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring, "As of 1.9, a string is only considered to be HTML if it starts with a less-than ("<") character."

```
var html = $( "ul.foo" ).html();
html = html.replace(/^[ \r\n\t]+/g,'');//remove leading whitespace
var nodes = $(html);
```

Answer (score -3):

The mistake is here:

```
var html = $( "ul.foo" ).html();
var nodes = $( html );
```

Rather do it like this:

```
var html = $( "ul.foo" ).html();
var nodes = $( html );
```

I tested it and it works

Comment: It's the same two lines twice. If the top one doesn't work, the bottom one won't either...

Comment: Oh crap. I copied and pasted and forgot to edit the Answer. It should be `var nodes = html;`